# How to add city list to Magento onepage checkout?

Tags: php, magento

I'm developing Magento site for local business. Thus i need to remove country list and add list of cities from checkout page.

How can i do it ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have the same cities list for shipping and billing address forms? How many cities do you want to show?

Comment: @ceckoslab Yes, I need city list instead of Country list. No need of Country list since they don't ship items internationally. I can't say number of cities specifically. I will need to list all available cities.

Answer (score 0):

Once we faced The same problem with one of our clients and since they did not want to pay for a full featured module we used a trick. We simply treated regions as countries and cities as regions. to do this you should add the name of your regions to your Zend respective locale data file and modify these three tables respectively:

1- directory_country
2- directory_country_region
3- directory_country_region_name

Comment: Thanks, Is there any per-developed extensions to do that task ?